# Deadlock Simple Scheduler

Tags: database, scheduler

Consider on simple scheduler, assume we have ordered (numbered) all objects: how to prove that if all transactions access objects in that order, then no deadlock can happen?

This is what I know: In simple scheduler, the scheduler will prevent any operation that could cause the set of open transaction not to be data-disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is for the assignment that is due soon.
I won't answer it fully for you, but think about maybe formulating a proof by contradiction. 
Start by assuming that all objects are ordered and that there is a circular wait (something that is essential for a deadlock). So maybe Pn wants r1, which P0 is holding, but P0 wants r2, which P1 is holding.
Think about what that might mean in terms of ordering and think about the case where Pn is waiting for something less than rn, as it would have to be for a circular wait to be in effect.

I feel like this is confusingly worded, but hopefully it puts you on the right track!!